# In VS Code, I save the file. But then curson automatically jumps on the new line

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VS Code...
I was commenting some notes I took.
I typed only - // and then saved (CTRL + S).
The cursor moved to the next line rather than staying on the line where I was gonna put the notes inside //
What should I do to make the cursor stay on the same line when I save?

Comment: are you using the prettier extension? do you have `editor.formatOnSave` on?

Comment: Oh, Yes! Now I get it!

Comment: now you get what? what did you change and what do you observe after making that change?

Comment: When the auto formatting in on - it will automatically move the cursor to the next line if there's a // Comment tag on the line before, there was nothing I could do. So I left it as it was as I need the auto formatting.